# How to mock AbstractValidator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I am failing on the BeUniqueEmail with the error message (below). How can I mock this correctly? I have included the validator and the test below.

The tests passed when I removed the BeUnique email validation

Message:
System.NotImplementedException : The method or operation is not implemented.

```
public class CreateStudentCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateStudentCommand>
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CreateStudentCommandValidator(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        RuleFor(v => v.Email)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email is required.")
            .MaximumLength(30).WithMessage("Email must not exceed 30 characters.")
            .MustAsync(BeUniqueEmail).WithMessage("The specified email already exists.");
    }

    public async Task<bool> BeUniqueEmail(CreateStudentCommand model, string email, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        bool emailExists = await _context.Students
                    .Where(x => x.Email == email)
                    .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                    .CountAsync() > 0;

        return !emailExists;
    }
}
```

Testing

```
    [Test]
        public async Task CreateStudentCommand_Success()
        {

            
            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Student>>();
            var context = new Mock<IApplicationDbContext>();
            context.Setup(m => m.Student).Returns(mockSet.Object);

            var handler = new CreateStudentCommandHandler(context.Object);
            var validator = new CreateStudentCommandValidator(context.Object);

            //var mockedValidator = new Mock<IValidator<CreateStudentCommandValidator>>();
            //var mock1 = new Mock<AbstractValidator<CreateStudentCommandValidator>>();
            
            var command = new CreateStudentCommand
            {
                StudentType = "Test1",
                Email = "Test1@email.com",
                FirstName = "Test1",
                LastName = "Test1",
                IsActive = true
            };

            var result = await handler.Handle(command, new CancellationToken());

            // Act
            var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(command);

            // Assert
            Assert.True(validationResult.IsValid);

            Assert.IsInstanceOf<Guid>(result);
        }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `.CountAsync() > 0` should be `.AnyAsync()` the latter being clearer and much faster.

Comment: Am I mis-reading? But in BeUniqueEmail you are accessing a property called "Students", but you are setting up a property called "Student" in your test

Comment: Originally im using AllAsync but this is not working on EFCore 3

Comment: When you post the code, you shall post everything, to imitate the issue, so much code need to return, in short, your mocking has issue, since original code may have `System.NotImplementedException` , but while mocking it doesn't call the original method it just returns the mocked value, but in your case original code might  be getting called. You may try replacing Exception with Valid Values and you would see Unit Test would get that value

Comment: Don't mock `DbContext` use in Memory provider or actual database.

Comment: @fabio canyou please provide an example?

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

Answer (score 1):

Using Moq, a solution to this could be as follows.

```
    [Test]
    public async Task TestValidation()
    {
        var context = Mock.Of<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var validator = new CreateStudentCommandValidator(context);

        var command = new CreateStudentCommand
        {
            StudentType = "Test1",
            Email = "Test1@email.com",
            FirstName = "Test1",
            LastName = "Test1",
            IsActive = true
        };


        var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(command);
        Assert.True(validationResult.IsValid);
    }
```

Not knowing your Context, I implemented a simple dummy.

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

This all depends on the use of Moq however, If you are using some other Mocking Service the Implementation will change.

*My Previous answer was intended to explain the implementation of Mocking Method Results. But in this case you do not need to mock the `CreateStudentCommandValidator`

Comment: Thanks! I tried this one but the validator does not contain a definition for Setup

Comment: You would need to Mock it first. Like you mocked the context. `var context = new Mock<IApplicationDbContext>();`

Comment: var mockedValidator = new Mock<CreateStudentCommandValidator>();
            mockedValidator.Setup(v => v.BeUniqueEmail(It.IsAny<CreateStudentCommand>(), It.IsAny<string>(), 
                It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));

Comment: I tried that but its giving me: System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: v => v.BeUniqueEmail(It.IsAny<CreateStudentCommand>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    Non-overridable members (here: CreateStudentCommandValidator.BeUniqueEmail) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Comment: which Mocking Service are you using. Moq?, It appears that the expression is Invalid, could be due to the use of the It.IsAny. the arguments for the method needs to be matched.

Comment: I have Updated the Answer, with a more detailed Implementation.

Comment: While you Mock a Function, and use something like `It.IsAny<CreateStudentCommand>()`, then there shall be explicit mock created for every object passed in the method